A infimum of integral of a cubic function

Let $f(x)$ be a cubic function defined on $[0,1]$, and $\max_{x \in [0,1]}\left|f(x) \right|=1$. Find the infimum of $$C=\int_0^{1}\left|f(x) \right|\text{d}x.$$

Note that $$C=\inf\int_0^{1}\left|f(x) \right|\text{d}x\,/\max_{x \in [0,1]}\left|f(x) \right|$$ when the condition of maximum is deleted.
I initially guess that $C=\dfrac{1}{4}$ where $f(x)=x^3$, but It is wrong actually.
Anyway, I turned to linear functions and obviously the answer is $C_1=\sqrt{2}-1$, but for quadratic functions it becomes tough. Mathematica told me when $f(x)=x^2-0.705x+0.087,$ $C_2$ can reach $0.227774$. And for cubic functions, $C_3$ can reach $0.145263$ where $f(x)=x^3-1.091x^2+0.307x-0.018$.
So my question is can we evaluate the closed form of $C_2,C_3$ and $C_n$?

Some thoughts.
We use Maple and Mathematica.
(1) Let $f(x) = x + a$. We have
$$C_1^2 = \inf_{x \in [0, 1];\,\, a\in \mathbb{R}} \frac{\left(\int_0^1 |f(y)|\,\mathrm{d} y\right)^2}{f^2(x)} = 3 - 2\sqrt{2}.$$
(2) Let $f(x) = x^2 + ax + b$. We have
$$C_2^2 = \inf_{x \in [0, 1]; \,\, a,\, b \in \mathbb{R}} \frac{\left(\int_0^1 |f(y)|\,\mathrm{d} y\right)^2}{f^2(x)} = 1 - 2q - 2\sqrt{-15 - q^2 + \frac{2}{q}}$$
where
$$q := \sqrt{-5 + \sqrt[3]{18 + 6\sqrt{3}} + \frac{6}{\sqrt[3]{18 + 6\sqrt{3}}}}.$$
(Note: $C_2\approx 0.2277742089975$. $C_2^2$ is a real root of $x^4-4x^3+126x^2-180x+9= 0$.)
